# .htaccess rewrite multiple urls in the same directory

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite some URL's but because i'm kind of a .htaccess noob, I have no idea how to make it myself.

So far I have:
`example(.)com/server/SERVERNAME` that goes to `example(.)com/server/index.php?server=SERVERNAME`

For this I use:

```
RewriteBase /server/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?server=$1 [L]
```

But from this point i'm stuck. 
I want `example(.)com/server/SERVERNAME/vote/` to go to `example(.)com/server/vote.php?server=SERVERNAME`

It may sound weird or confusing, but I have no idea if it's even possible or not.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `/server/` a real directory?

Comment: @anubhava Yes, /server/ is a real directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be missing `RewriteEngine On` and also you need more than 1 rule to check whether matching `.php` file exists in `/server/`.

Place this rule in `/server/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /server/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/server/$2\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $2.php?server=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?server=$1 [L,QSA]
```